# MSBuild x64 folder nearly empty

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have recently updated to W10 (x64) and noticed that I had loads of files on my MSBuild on Program Files (x86) (so I can compile using VS without any problem), but inside my MSBuild folder on Program Files, there is only a file called `Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeTools.Targets` and a folder called `Microsoft`

Inside that folder, paths `C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Windows Workflow Foundation\v3.0` and `C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Windows Workflow Foundation\v3.5` there are only two files called `Workflow.Targets` and `Workflow.VisualBasic.Targets`

Should I reinstall Visual Studio? Anything wrong here? I just find it a bit weird that there are no executables to build x64 programs with VS

Thanks

Comment: The 32 bit MSBuild is capable enough.

Comment: This is normal, don't fix anything.  Common Microsoft oops btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, that's how the directory should be.

The exact `msbuild.exe` was nowhere near `Program Files` directory, it's in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 (or whatever version you wanna use)`.

Comment: Just asked a friend to check his folder and you're absolutely right, just as mine.
Thanks!

Comment: @vagaerg Glad to help ;-)